# OpenGL ES 1: Fog and texture transparency

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have some very old android apps using OpenGL ES 1.x that I need to update in Google Play in order to make them work on newer devices. After doing the needed updates of deprecated code etc, I found that where I'm using fog, textures with transparency now no longer works. The transparent parts are showing slightly. If I turn off fog everything works fine though.

This was all working fine when I deployed the apps and has been tested through the years without issues. But apparently something has changed now.

Is there anyone that still has knowledge about OpenGL ES 1.x who can help with this? Here's the part of my code applying the fog and then drawing all the quads:

```
        gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_MODE, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_FOG_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_START, startZ);
        gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_END, endZ);
        gl.glFogfv(GL10.GL_FOG_COLOR, fColor, 0);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_FOG);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        super.drawSprites(gl);

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_FOG);
```

And here's an example of how it renders when fog is on, as you see the transparent parts of the quads are showing:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a device specific problem. My test phone was a Samsung Galaxy s22 ultra, and when testing on other devices (including the s21 ultra) no other phone shows the same error. So I will mark this as the answer. Thanks to @solidpixel for helping out with the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `GL_ALPHA_TEST` to cull the transparent fragments  so you are picking up fog color on the transparent parts of each sprite.

Comment: I added a `gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);` before my drawSprites but the result is the same. Did you refer to another alpha test? And as mentioned before this _has_ been working in earlier android/phone versions.

Comment: What's the `glAlphaFunc()` you have set?

Comment: "this has been working in earlier android/phone versions", so? It's obviously not now ...

We're working with a very incomplete reproducer, so shooting in the dark somewhat.

Comment: Re: "it was working", yeah I just meant that it might be a clue if there is some known change in later versions of opengl es 1.x implementations in android versions or how GPU is handling stuff. :)

Anyway I didn't have any `glAlphaFunc` set at all, but have now tried different variants
`gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_ALWAYS, 0.0f);` and GL_GREATER but still the same result...

Comment: If this happens only on a specific device then it's possible a driver bug. If it's widespread then likely an application problem, but without a more complete repro it's impossible to say.

Comment: Yeah just tried building to an old Galaxy Note 8 and no problem with transparency there. But on my Galaxy S22 Ultra the problem is as described above.

Comment: If it's device specific, then I'd raise a bug on the Samsung forums. S22 is the new Samsung Xclipse GPU, so assume the driver stack is a little less mature than Adreno/Mali.

Comment: Yeah problem seems to be pinned to my s22, tried it on last year's model s21 ultra and that one works fine as well. So I guess this is nothing I can fix, if not porting all code to OpenGL 2 or 3 instead but that seems like too much work for now.